# Lets encrypt failed authorization procedure - docker

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, lets-encrypt

i'm trying to setup https certs for my site. Since i'm using docker containers , i have set up the following config

1. Node serves public content to a named driver called static-content
2. this driver is accessed and served by nginx

my docker-compose file

```
version : '2'

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    links:
      - web:web
    volumes:
      - /etc/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt/
      - /etc/ssl:/etc/ssl
      - static-content:/usr/src/app

  web:
    container_name: web
    image: kannaj/42exp
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - ./logs:/usr/src/app/logs
      - static-content:/usr/src/app/public
    expose:
      - "8000"
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=production

    command: npm run package

volumes:
  static-content:
```

running `docker volume inspect static-content` shows the below

```
[
    {
        "Driver": "local",
        "Labels": null,
        "Mountpoint": "/var/lib/docker/volumes/www_static-content/_data",
        "Name": "www_static-content",
        "Options": {},
        "Scope": "local"
    }
]
```

I then run 
`sudo certbot certonly --force-renewal --webroot -w /var/lib/docker/volumes/www_static-content/_data -d 42exp.com -d www.42exp.com`

but i get the following errors

```
  Domain: 42exp.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://42exp.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/KbQko2Y6lZfiDcbZ-dF7DTchX3G__wmZVMMn4xT8tjs
   [139.162.21.71]: 404

   Domain: www.42exp.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.42exp.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/gHHrVOYg9OfLznO7SiH_HTo6A6SGLpUHYuJax1U65ws
   [139.162.21.71]: 404
```

After some research , i added the below to my server block in nginx assuming that certbot isnt able to reach the domain

```
  location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
    }
```

I got a different 404 response now

```
IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: www.42exp.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://www.42exp.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/dWH2F9pApDnElq8jpqiykaylqUF7NR-RZ8MmWTg1NRA:
   "<html>
   <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
   <body bgcolor="white">
   <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
   <hr><center>"

   Domain: 42exp.com
   Type:   unauthorized
   Detail: Invalid response from
   http://42exp.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/z_A7WOrYzEEu0RvmAFkgpNCz9ONNYByGc3RkdeqmJDo:
   "<html>
   <head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
   <body bgcolor="white">
   <center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
   <hr><center>"

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

I had a look at my static content folder and there does seem to be a `.well-known` folder. I'm not sure why i'm still getting a 404. 
Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mention in [this thread](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/ubuntu-16-04-nginx-error-type-unauthorized-detail-invalid-response/19500/2):

- Is the web root you specify correct ?
- if you place a file at /usr/src/app/.well-known/acme-challenge/test can you reach it at http://www.42exp.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/test ?

It looks like that test file does not exist, and that NGiNX returns the content of the `404.html` page.

As [seen here](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/http-01-urn-acme-error-unauthorized-and-404-not-found/28450), the certbot path might not be correct. See [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04) (not in a docker context, but can still give you some clues)

In any case, check the nginx logs in order to see what is being accessed.

You need to mention where  /.well-known should point to: root /usr/src/app;
But see "[NGiNX Pitfalls and Common Mistakes](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/)"

> Putting `root` inside of a location block will work and it’s perfectly valid.
>
> What’s wrong is when you start adding location blocks. If you add a `root` to every location block then a location block that isn’t matched will have no root.
>
> Therefore, it is important that a `root` directive occur prior to your location blocks, which can then override this directive if they need to.

Comment: Turns out i had to include a root directive along with the 'allow all' command. looks to work fine now. thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out i had to include a root directive here

```
 location ~ /.well-known {
            root /usr/src/app;
            allow all;
    }
```